# How to change background color using TabBarIOS on React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Is anyone can help ?

I have tried many different way but still not working....

I used react-native-icons and it can change background, but I can't find the way to change icons to my own images...

Comment: I asked similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322721/tabbarios-on-react-native-not-working-as-expected and there it was pointed out that custom icons / images can't yet be used.

So at this point I think the "best" solution is to create custom components by extending tab bar solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can change background-color in "react-native-icons".

You can choose icons only from icon font.

```
<SMXTabBarItemIOS
   name="home"
   iconName={'ion|ios-home-outline'}
   title={'Home'}
   iconSize={30}
   ...
   ...
</SMXTabBarItemIOS>
```

Right now is not possible to change inactive tab text/icon color from iOS default gray. You can change only active/selected tab text/icon color via "tintColor".